# Nextjs App Deployed on IIS Server Stopping after some time and full page reload

Tags: reactjs, iis, next.js, frontend

I have built a nextjs app and deployed it on IIS Server using IISNode. The app is working properly. But there are two problems, the first after some days the app is stopping unexpectedly and the IIS Application Pool of this app is stopped, i don't know what is the issue. The second issue sometimes the modal of "full page reload" is showing on production, i know that this modal is showing on development whenever anyone updates the files.

Can anyone knows how to resolve these problem?

Comment: To diagnose why the application pool is stopping, first review the logs. The IIS logs and Windows Event Viewer may contain errors or warnings related to your application or application pool.

Comment: I reviewed the event viewer already but there are no logs related to IIS Pool stop. I think because it's related to IISNode itself

Comment: Will the website run normally after you restart the apppool? Will the application pool still stop unexpectedly? The modal of "full page reload" typically occurs when your Next.js application detects changes in your code. It is recommended to use the correct deployment pipeline and avoid making live code changes on the server.

Comment: Yes we use the correct deployment pipeline and there are times we deploy changes but most of the time there are no changes and however the full page reload happen from time to time. Regarding the application pool yes it stops unexpectedly i don't know why may it related npm process and iis process

Comment: If your application pool stops unexpectedly again, maybe debug Diagnostics Tool (DebugDiag) can be a lifesaver, it creates and analyze IIS crash dumps. IIS Application Pool Crash and Debug Diag:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/parvez/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag. But analyzing dump files is a complex process, so I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, 
there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.

Comment: We use a custom node server script in nextjs and using the IISNode module in IIS so that the IIS can communicate with the custom server in behind to launch the app and this is working but it seems that the IISNode has something wrong as in certain times it crashes and shows 500 Server Error, i don't know exactly what is the problem.

Comment: Try using FRT to view details about the 500 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Failed request tracing not work as i think as this is not a .net app, it's nextjs app running using the IISNode module so IIS can't detect such failures